# The command "python" ... failed! No puedo ejecutar un script de Python en Laravel

Tags: laravel, python-3.x, script, laravel-7, laragon

Tengo un proyecto en laravel y necesito ejecutar algunos archivos escritos en python, utilice este codigo en mi controlador de laravel:

```
    $process = new Process(['python', 'C:/laragon/www/Python/main.py']);
    $process->run();

    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    echo $process->getOutput();
```

y me da este error:
[image: laravel]

tengo python instalado y el script lo corre bien en el cmd pero aquí no.

Además quería saber si puedo utilizar ese script y que este llame a otros archivos en python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Pacientes import Paciente
def main():
    print("hola")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Como de la carpeta pacientes importar la clase Paciente

Comment: y si le das la ruta completa a python? Tu python acorde al environment no es el mismo que ven otros usuarios, o no necesariamente

Comment: como la ruta completa?? hablas de la ruta de python que esta en el controlador?

Comment: Claro. Por ejemplo si fuera Linux habría que poner "/usr/bin/python3" porque python por si mismo es el alias con que un usuario invoca a uno de los 3 o más intérpretes disponibles (3.6, 2.7, 3.8, etc)

Comment: el error dice que python no esta instalado, cambia python por ´py´

Comment: cambie esta parte Process(['python'... por Process(['py' ...y mi pantalla se queda en blanco, deberia regresar el print que tengo en el script?

Comment: Con respecto a la ruta, tengo la ruta completa, esa carpeta llamada Python esta guardada en el www de Laragon